# How to get the count of digits after the comma of a double-number in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, double

Examples:

Double-Number is 56.6789 result should be 4

Double-Number is 12345.67  result should be 2

Double-Number is 12345.6  result should be 1

I have a solution tinkering with strings, but I think there is an mathematical solution?

Please in VB.NET ...

Comment: Convert it `ToString` and then use SubString and Length to find your answer.

Comment: What do you want to happen for a double such as (1/3), where there would be an infinite number of digits?

Answer (score 3):

Split the original number and get the length of the upper index (1)

```
myNumber = 12.3456

Dim count As Integer = Len(Split(CStr(myNumber), Application.DecimalSeparator)(1))

Debug.Print count // prints '4'
```

---

*edit: replaced "." with decimal separator to ensure use across varying cultures*

Comment: This isn't culture-specific

Comment: @simonalexander2005 OP hasn't asked for it to be - but as you've pointed it out I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Dim x As String = CStr(56.6789)
Dim count = x.Length - InStr(x, ".")
```

Comment: This isn't culture-specific

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to keep knocking off the whole part, multiplying by 10, repeat until you have an integer:

```
Dim x As Double = 1.23456
Dim count As Integer = 0
While Math.Floor(x) <> x
    x = (x - Math.Floor(x)) * 10D
    count = count + 1
End While
```

Note this will fail if there is an infinite number of decimal places - so you could set a limit on it (`If count > 100 Then Exit While`)

Another way would be like this, which converts to a string but removes the need to hardcode the separator.

```
Dim x As Double = 1.23456
Dim x0 As Double = x - Math.Floor(x)
Dim x0String As String = x0.ToString()
Dim count As Integer = x0String.Substring(2, x0String.Length - 2).Length
```

Using `Application.DecimalSeparator` also allows a string to be used.

The method with a string will again lose information about an infinite-length fractional part, as it will truncate it.